# new column each row results from a query to mysql database in R

Tags: sql, r, rmysql

I've got a simple dataframe with three columns. One of the columns contains a database name. I first need to check if data exists, and if not, insert it. Otherwise do nothing.

Sample data frame:

```
clientid;region;database
135;Europe;europedb
2567;Asia;asiadb
23;America;americadb
```

So I created a function to apply to dataframe this way:

```
library(RMySQL)

    check_if_exist <- function(df){

    con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                       user="myuser", password="mypass",
                       dbname=df$database, host="myhost")

    query <- paste0("select count(*) from table where client_id='", df$clientid,"' and region='", df$region ,"'")

    rs <- dbSendQuery(con, query)

    rs

    }
```

Function call:

```
df$new_column <- lapply(df, check_if_exist)
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example of what you are asking, if I understood correctly. But I don't have your database, so we just print the query for verification, and fetch a random number as the result.

Note that by doing `lapply(df,...)`, you are looping over the columns of the database, and not the rows as you want.

```
df = read.table(text="clientid;region;database
135;Europe;europedb
2567;Asia;asiadb
23;America;americadb",header=T,sep=";")


check_if_exist <- function(df){
  query = paste0("select count(*) from table where client_id='", df$clientid,"' and region='", df$region ,"'")
  print(query)
  rs <- runif(1,0,1)
  return(rs)
}

df$new_column <- sapply(split(df,seq(1,nrow(df))),check_if_exist)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: seems to work, thanks, but new column has no data, just `<S4 object of class 'MySQLResult>`

Comment: maybe add `rs=dbFetch(rs)` or `rs=dbFetch(rs)[[1]]
` before outputting in your function, see [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DBI/versions/0.5-1/topics/dbSendQuery)

Comment: worked with rs=dbFetch(rs)[[1]]   thanks, now I can follow my procedure